# can't process massive Azure Analysis Services Tabular cube

Tags: azure, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I have a problem with an Azure Tabular cube that I can not solve.

I can't get the process through.

Basically, there is a fact table of 16,000,000,000 rows.
And a customer dimension of 900,000 rows.
And four more small dimensions.

I have AAS at the highest level S9 but I run out of memory anyway.

I've tried to process data first on the tables and the recalc, but it still crashes.

I'm starting the processing manually in SSMS, if that has anything to do with it.

I google and google but i cant find any answers on azure tabular limits or patterns how to tackle massive datasets.

Is it to much data?
Or is there a process to this that i am missing?

Comment: When you split up the processing in a data step followed by a recalc, does it crash during the recalc? If so, this indicates that you have one or more calculated columns on your fact table, which is a very bad idea for such a big table. See if you can move these calculated columns to your ETL, so that you can import them as regular data columns.

Comment: Did it fail on the process data or recalc?

Comment: Please build a partition that has some representative subset like 200,000,000 rows and  process full it. Then use https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/data-model-size-with-vertipaq-analyzer/ to tell us the largest memory consuming columns and their data type. Maybe we can help shrink them. For example a datetime column can be split into a date column and a time column which massively reduces memory usage.